# Moving Log Files To A Backup File

Tags: bash, logging, solaris

I want to move my Log Files to a backup folder. First let me give detail about my directory structure.
Log files are located in `/appdata2/wlslogs/ccbdomain/` . Under this folder there are `AdminServer` , `ccbdoamin11` Under them there are log files as `ccb_server11_err.out00001` `access.log00004` `ccb_server11.out00001`. I want move those files to `/appdata2/wlslogs/ccbdomain_backup/backup$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`.

For that matter I have written a script as

```
logpath=/appdata2/wlslogs/ccbdomain/
backuppath=/appdata2/wlslogs/back_up/

mkdir $backuppath/backup$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
find $logpath .  -type f -mtime +4 | egrep 'log0|out0|err0' | nawk '$1' | xargs mv  $backuppath/backup$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

The problem with that it does not see my `logpath` and searhes for every directory under the directory script is run.

Also I am not sure if I can use `mv` without any option there.

Edit: Can you help me with also `cp` command. I have tried everything all works. But I can't take the risk to move files. I wanted to copy instead. However I can't find the option to put after `cp`. In many pages they say `-t` to use. I guess that option is not valid in Solaris.

```
find $logpath  -type f -mtime +4 | egrep 'log0|out0|err0' | nawk '$1' | xargs cp -t  $backuppath/
```

Comment: "find $logpath ."

for search start path you should use one - "$logpath" or ".", both of them looks like syntax error

Comment: Thanks for your command. İt helped.